# Как добавить к существующей переменной значение

Tags: python

у меня есть изначальное значение перменной 2, и я хочу чтоб когда пользователь вводил текст, к переменной добавлялось +1. Ниже код как я приблизительно все это вижу но никак не могу понять как это реализовать

```
money = 2
text = input("your text: ")
if text == "hello":
    money = money + 1
```

Comment: А в чем проблема? Код в вопросе рабочий, `money` будет равно `3`. PS. инкремент можно проще делать: `money += 1`

Comment: Уверен, что ваш вопрос, на самом деле про `Мнительность`: https://liza.ua/lifestyle/self-development/chto-takoe-mnitelnost-i-kak-s-ney-borotsya/

Comment: @gil9red спасибо за ответ, но так же я имел ввиду как сделать так чтоб переменная при добавлении, изменялась в значении на програмном уровне, то есть система должна запомнить что было 2, пользователь написал hello и к переменной добавилось 1 и стало 3, а потом опять если написать hello то будет уже 4

Comment: Тогда используйте цикл, например `while true: text .... if text == ...: money = ...`

Comment: А для того, чтобы выйти из цикла проверяйте text на, например, 'exit', или 'quit', или 'q'. Что-то типа if text == 'exit': break

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Способов много. Вот например один из них.

```
money = 2
while money < 100:
    text = input("your text: ")
    money += 1 #так не только проще, но и работает быстрее
    print(money)
    print(text)
```

Можно вообще бд подрубить и каждый раз в базу данных записывать обновленное значение, когда происходит запись в переменную text

Так же вы можете написать функцию и вызывать каждый раз ее для пользовательского ввода:

```
money = 0
def ForInput(money):
    text = input("your text: ")
    money += 1
    return(money)

money = ForInput(money)
```